# Regex find pattern leave old value

Tags: c#, regex

How should look like replace regex for this problem:

Input: `2011,01,10   a,john.doe@gimail.com`

I want to have: `2011,01,10   a.john.doe@gmail.com`

I write method like this:

```
public static string CorrectSmallMistakes(string email)
{
    string result;
    string pattern = "gimail\\.";
    string replacment = "gmail.";

    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

    email= rgx.Replace(email, replacment);

    pattern = @"(\w,)";
    replacment = "\\w\\.";

    rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    result = rgx.Replace(email, replacment);

    return result;
}
```

For replacing gimail to gmail is ok, but for a, to a. is not working. I got

```
201\w\.0\w\.10   \w\.emil.rutkowski1986@gmail.com
```

How do I need to write replacment to leave old values?

Comment: `\w` matches letters as well as digits.

Comment: Use `result=Regex.Replace(email, @"(?<=\p{L}),", ".")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\p{L}` to match only letters. Use zero-length [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a literal replacement of `"."`:

```
pattern = @"(?<=\p{L}),";
replacment = ".";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(email, replacment);
```

This way the `\w` portion would be checked, but not made part of the match.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/EgIjpj)